# Mysql count frequency

Tags: mysql, arrays, count, frequency

I've checked similar questions but it didnt help in my precise question.

So, my table goes like this:

```
id age
1  30
2  36
3  30
4  52
5  52
6  30
7  36
```

etc..

I need to count the frequency of ages:

```
age freq
30   2
36   3
52   2
```

How can I grab this freq?
After this I will need to work with that data, so it might be necessary using array?
Thanks!

```
function drawChart() {

      // Create the data table.

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'age');
      data.addColumn('number', 'freq');

        <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
            {
            $frequencies[$row[0]] = $frequencies[1];
            echo "data.addRow(['{$row[0]}', {$row[1]}]);";
            }

        ?>
```

The goal is build a chart

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to group the rows by the common age, then count how many are in each group:

```
SELECT age, COUNT(*) AS freq FROM ages GROUP BY age
```

To then convert it into an array, do this in PHP:

```
$frequencies = array ();
$result = mysql_query('SELECT age, COUNT(*) AS freq FROM table GROUP BY age');
if($result === false) { handle error here... }
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $frequencies[$row[0]] = $row[1];
}
```

You now have an associative array called $frequencies with the ages as keys and their frequency as values.

Comment: Yes, Im using php and javascript

Comment: Im printing the frequencies array and it shows only the ages, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @skdnewbie how are you printing the array? use `var_dump($frequencies)` to see the whole array as PHP sees it

Comment: hmm, array seems fine with var_dump, I might be using it wrong then.

Answer (score 2):

```
select age, name, count(*) freq from user_age group by age
```

Sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/266d5/2

Answer (score 0):

```
select age, count(*) freq from mytable group by age
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select age, count(id) as freq from table group by age
```