# Mysql count frequency - with threshold

Tags: mysql, frequency

Posts like [Mysql count frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13398116/mysql-count-frequency) were useful in getting a frequency list of a field in a MySQL table.

What if I'd like to set a threshold, so that only some frequencies that fulfil a criteria are "selected" or shown. eg.

```
SELECT age, COUNT(*) AS freq FROM ages GROUP BY age WHERE COUNT(*) > 20
```

The above command gets an error though. What is the correct command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use HAVING but you have to do the filter on the new field "freq":

```
SELECT age, COUNT(*) AS freq
FROM ages
GROUP BY age
HAVING freq > 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `HAVING` clause here:

```
SELECT age, COUNT(*) AS freq
FROM ages
GROUP BY age
HAVING COUNT(*) > 20;
```

`HAVING` plays a similar role as `WHERE`, except the former acts on *groups* or aggregates of records, whereas the latter acts on individual records.  Since you want to restrict the behavior of groups of records, after doing a `GROUP BY`, you want to use `HAVING`.

Comment: Another way to think about it is that the `WHERE` clause filters the data before `GROUP`ing occurs while the `HAVING` clause filters the data after the `GROUP`ing occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Move your where clause to before your group by:

```
SELECT 
    age, 
    COUNT(*) AS freq 
FROM ages 
WHERE COUNT(*) > 20
GROUP BY age
```

Comment: this did not work for me. #1111 - Invalid use of group function